# Can't access JS function in a different JS file?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>some_stuff</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="img/ico" href="/some_stuff/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/some_stuff/stylesheets/main.css">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some_stuff/javascripts/main.js"></script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY_API_KEY>&callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

This is the contents of my `main.js`:

```
function initialize() {
    console.log("Initialized!");
    // Do other stuff to render the map
    renderMap();
}
```

For some reason, this is throwing the error `Uncaught TypeError: window.initialize is not a function` in the browser.

However, if I change my code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>some_stuff</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="img/ico" href="/some_stuff/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/some_stuff/stylesheets/main.css">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some_stuff/javascripts/main.js"></script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY_API_KEY>&callback=initialize">
    </script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            console.log("Initialized!")
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

and `main.js` just contains

```
renderMap()
```

then everything works. What gives?

Comment: You are probably not referring to the correct directory, check to make sure your script loaded for `main.js`.

Comment: @TheShaman your suggestion makes no sense.

Comment: What if you put `debugger;` into the `main.js`: would it break before google maps sdk triggers an arror?

Comment: Yes, the order should not affect callbacks. Anyway, I'm inclined to believe that you are calling `renderMap()` as soon as the script is loaded and luckily the async js file is already loaded at that point. Other than that, I'd like to know if the *`"Initialized"`* string is being logged to the console.

Comment: Check the order of JavaScript files in the dev console's Network Panel. Just by taking a gander at it I don't know why you have `async` and `defer` both on the same tag. Here's [more](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html) info on it. I would get rid of async if I were you and try again. Let me know. I'm interested on this one too.